# Como puedo extraer un color en especifico de una imagen con js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, background

Hola que tal como están? ESpero que bastante bien. Les platico, estoy haciendo un proyecto que me ha estado volviendo loca. Quiero extraer un color de una imagen, lo intente poner un contenedor para la imagen pero el problema es que si yo ponía una imagen con otras dimensiones mi imagen se iba a distorsionar. Así que decidí poner solo el contenedor y poner como propiedades del css (como background) la imagen. Con esto logre que unque yo subiera una imagen muy larga o muy ancha mi main no se iba a estar moviendo tanto. El problema que tengo es que intente aplicar la misma "metodología" que si fuera una imagen normal, pero cada que le intento saber el rgb me sale 0. Ya intente de todas las formas posibles y no puedo. Si alguien me pudiera ayudar se lo agradecería mucho (Ignoren que no es responsive, eso lo iba a dejar al final, ya cuando lo acabara :D)

```js
const imagenSubida = document.getElementById('container_img');
const colorRGB= document.getElementById('color_rbg');
const colorHexa = document.getElementById('color_hexa');
const btnSubirImagen = document.getElementById('upload_image');
const fileUpload = document.getElementById('fileUpload');
//parte para cargar la imagen que queramos
fileUpload.addEventListener('change', ()=>{
    imagenSubida.style.removeProperty('backgroundImage');
    const archivo = fileUpload.files;
    const imagen = archivo[0];
    const backgroundImage =URL.createObjectURL(imagen);
    imagenSubida.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + backgroundImage +')';

})


//parte para crear el canva
// const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
// const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// canvas.width = imagenSubida.offsetWidth;
// canvas.height = imagenSubida.offsetHeight;

// canvas.style.width = imagenSubida.offsetWidth + 'px';
// canvas.style.height = imagenSubida.offsetHeight + 'px';

// imagenSubida.appendChild(canvas);

// canvas.addEventListener('click', function(e){
//     const x = e.offsetX;
//     const y = e.offsetY;
    
//     // Obtener los datos de color del píxel en la posición (x, y)
//     const imageData = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
//     const pixel = imageData.data;

//     // Normalizar los valores de color para que estén en el rango [0, 1]
//     const colorR = pixel[0] / 255;
//     const colorG = pixel[1] / 255;
//     const colorB = pixel[2] / 255;

//     // Formatear el color en formato RGB
//     const colorRGB = 'RGB: ' + colorR + ', ' + colorG + ', ' + colorB;

//     console.log('Coordenadas del clic - X:', x, 'Y:', y);
//     console.log('Color del píxel:', colorRGB);
// });
imagenSubida.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    const backgroundImage = new Image();
    backgroundImage.src = getComputedStyle(this).backgroundImage.replace(/(url\(|\)|")/g, '');
    
        const canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
        canvas.width = imagenSubida.width;
        canvas.height = imagenSubida.height;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0);
        const pixel = ctx.getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
        console.log(pixel);
    }
);
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #F2EBF0;
}
main{
    width:50% ;
    height: 80%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 13px;
    background-color: #049DBF;

}
input[type='file']{
    display: none;
}

.label{
    background-color: #8C2A3C;
    border-radius:8px ;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 8rem;
    height: 2rem;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.container_logo{
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 1.5rem;
}
.logo{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.boton{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
#imagen{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.container_img{

    display: inline-block; 
    width: 85%;
    height: 30rem;
    background: #049DBF;
    background-image: url('https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod/images/lilo-stitch-1676723190.jpg');
    background-position: center;
     background-repeat:  no-repeat; /* Establece el color de fondo y la imagen */
    background-size: contain; 
    cursor: crosshair;
     }
#preview{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
#resultados{
    width: 85%;
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.numero{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.resultado_color{
    width: 10rem;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
.numeros_colores{
    width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: end;
}
.prueba_color{
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.muestra_color{
    width: 45%;
    height: 4rem;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

@media  (max-width: 1540px) { 
    #imagen{
        margin: 0;

    }
    #resultados{
        margin-top: -5px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 768px){
    main{
        width: 85%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Colores </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <section id="subir_imagen">
            <div class="boton" >
                <label id="upload_image" class="label" for="fileUpload">
                    <div class="container_logo">
                        <img class="logo" src="resources/upload-photo-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    Subir Imagen</label>
                        <input type="file" id="fileUpload" accept=".jpg,.png"/>
            
            </div>
        </section>

        <section id="imagen">
            <div class="container_img" id="container_img">                
            </div>

        </section>

        <section id="resultados">
           
            <div class="numeros_colores">
                <div class="numero">
                    <p  id= "color_rbg"class="resultado_color">RBG</p>
                    <div class="container_logo">
                        <img src="resources/copy-svgrepo-com-white.svg" alt="" class="logo">
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="numero">
                    <p id="color_hexa" class="resultado_color">#000000</p>
                    <div class="container_logo">
                        <img src="resources/copy-svgrepo-com-white.svg" alt="" class="logo">
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
               
            </div>
            <div class="prueba_color">
                <div class="muestra_color">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estoy seguro de la razon por la que no te registraba los pixeles, pero puede que sea porque al clickear la imagen se activaban los 2 eventos: el de 'canvas' y el de 'imagenSubida', así que termine por usar un solo evento.

Después usas el tamaño de 'imagenSubida' para darle el tamaño al canvas, ese no es el tamaño del fondo sino el tamaño del div contenedor, entonces podrías tener imprecisiones por esa parte también.

Puedes volver al enfoque de usar `<img>`y acomodarla con CSS con propiedades como [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) para que se acomode al tamaño del contenedor, además podrás obtener el tamaño de la imagen fácilmente y la URL con la propiedad src.

```
<section id="imagen">
  <div class="container_img" id="container_img">
    <!-- el crossorigin es para que drawImage no nos tire error si la imagen viene de una url externa -->
    <img id="img" src="https://i.ibb.co/x57tw7t/asado-cocido.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous"></div> 
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.container_img {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 85%;
  height: 30rem;
  background: #049DBF;
}

#img {
  object-fit: contain;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-position: center;
}
```

Una vez clickeada la imagen, obtenido su tamaño y creado el canvas en base a ese tamaño, te faltarían 2 parámetros mas en la función drawImage, que te permitirán que la imagen encaje perfectamente en el canvas, le pasas tanto el ancho como el alto del canvas (o el alto y ancho de la imagen, es lo mismo).

De esta manera las coordenadas del mouse sobre la imagen funcionaran perfectamente para extrapolarlas al canvas y obtener la información del pixel.

Código completo:

```js
const imagenSubida = document.getElementById('container_img');
const colorRGB = document.getElementById('color_rbg');
const colorHexa = document.getElementById('color_hexa');
const btnSubirImagen = document.getElementById('upload_image');
const fileUpload = document.getElementById('fileUpload');
const img = document.getElementById('img')

fileUpload.addEventListener('change', () => {
  const archivo = fileUpload.files;
  const imagen = archivo[0];
  const backgroundImage = URL.createObjectURL(imagen);
  img.src = backgroundImage; 
})

img.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  const x = e.offsetX;
  const y = e.offsetY;
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = img.offsetWidth; // obtenemos alto y ancho de la imagen para asignarlo al alto y ancho del canvas
  canvas.height = img.offsetHeight;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // agregamos las 2 propiedades faltantes
  const pixel = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;

  const colorR = pixel[0];
  const colorG = pixel[1];
  const colorB = pixel[2];

  const colorRGB = 'RGB: ' + colorR + ', ' + colorG + ', ' + colorB;

  console.log('Coordenadas del clic - X:', x, 'Y:', y);
  console.log('Color del píxel:', colorRGB);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: min-content;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #F2EBF0;
}

main {
  width: 50%;
  height: 80%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 13px;
  background-color: #049DBF;

}

input[type='file'] {
  display: none;
}

.label {
  background-color: #8C2A3C;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 8rem;
  height: 2rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container_logo {
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
}

.logo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.boton {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#imagen {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.container_img {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 85%;
  height: 30rem;
  background: #049DBF;
}

#img {
  object-fit: contain;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-position: center;
}

#preview {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#resultados {
  width: 85%;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.numero {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.resultado_color {
  width: 10rem;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.numeros_colores {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: end;
}

.prueba_color {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.muestra_color {
  width: 45%;
  height: 4rem;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

@media (max-width: 1540px) {
  #imagen {
    margin: 0;

  }

  #resultados {
    margin-top: -5px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  main {
    width: 85%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <section id="subir_imagen">
      <div class="boton">
        <label id="upload_image" class="label" for="fileUpload">
          <div class="container_logo">
            <img class="logo" src="resources/upload-photo-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="">
          </div>
          Subir Imagen
        </label>
        <input type="file" id="fileUpload" accept=".jpg,.png" />
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="imagen">
      <div class="container_img" id="container_img">
        <!-- el crossorigin es para que drawImage no nos tire error si la imagen viene de una url externa -->
        <img id="img" src="https://i.ibb.co/x57tw7t/asado-cocido.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous">
      </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="resultados">
      <div class="numeros_colores">
        <div class="numero">
          <p id="color_rbg" class="resultado_color">RBG</p>
          <div class="container_logo">
            <img src="resources/copy-svgrepo-com-white.svg" alt="" class="logo">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="numero">
          <p id="color_hexa" class="resultado_color">#000000</p>
          <div class="container_logo">
            <img src="resources/copy-svgrepo-com-white.svg" alt="" class="logo">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="prueba_color">
        <div class="muestra_color">
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <script src="scripts2.js" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```